# getting error while enabling curl in php5 ubuntu

Tags: php, curl

I have installed curl in ubuntu server using this command

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git
```

it's succeeded now i am trying to enable this extension in php on linux platform.so i commented out the extension=php_curl.dll line in php.ini .But it giving this error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20131226/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

i got this error while confirming the whether curl is enabled in php with this command

```
php -i | grep curl
```

please help with me how to enable curl extension in php on linux platform

Comment: no need to delete and open a new question ...

Comment: hello vasil Shaddix if u got the my problem then answer.don't give this shitting comments as  
no need to delete and open a new question

Comment: You've installed Curl, and you've installed PHP, but I think you are missing the PHP-Curl integration libraries. `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

Comment: i am getting this error..please check this link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eXzc6qwHaK8BAeAxezwx_nDahRIHaioErF0WIzVLClM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have? You were trying to access a link for 14.04 (Trusty). In that version php5-curl is available from the main repository, not a PPA. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-curl That PPA appears only to be for 16.04 users.

Comment: ADyson...thank you so much.now got it.please add this in answer section.so it would be usefull to others..thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed Curl, and you've installed PHP, but I think you are missing the PHP-Curl integration libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

This is available from the main repository in 14.04 - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-curl

However from 16.04 onwards only PHP7 is included by default, so you'll probably have to use a 3rd-party PPA.